# Why am I not able to show the default android row selection color?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using this code to Implement the `ListView` with section:

```
  public class ListSample extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{   

    public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";   
    public final static String ITEM_CAPTION = "caption";   
    public Resources resources;
    public static Uri path;
    ImageAdapter customAdapter;
    private SeparatedListAdapter adapter;
    public static File file;
    public static ProgressDialog  m_progressDialog;
    public static ListView list;

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {   
        super.onCreate(icicle);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // create our list and custom adapter   
        adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this); 

       // customAdapter =new ImageAdapter(ListSample.this, R.layout.list_item,mList);

        adapter.addSection("Local documents:", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "WindowsONE Mobile PK", "WindowsorONE Moldings","Filet for a burger video" }));
        adapter.addSection("Non-local resources:", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "Launch Photo slideshow link", "Dealer locator link" }));
        adapter.addSection("Send emails:", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "Send Dealer Locator email", "Send Catalog email","Send install instrucation link" })); 
        //For extra Information in Listview    
        //adapter.addSection("Non-local resources:", new SimpleAdapter(this, security, R.layout.list_complex,   
        //new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));        
        list = getListView();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);   
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
       }
}
```

And if I run this application, all works fine.
But when select any row the action is done but I am not able to see any highlight color as like this row is selected(as like default android row selection color).

So, What should I have to do to make it possible ?

I want to show the highlight color when the particular row is selected.

Comment: You mean the color when the row is tapped? Or Long tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rowitem.xml must be having a background color. Remove this and you will see the default highlight color. If you want to customize the highlight, use a selector as flybirdx suggested

Comment: Is my code right to make appear that default row select colour ??

Comment: You haven't seem to have done anything from code that should disable the selector. You need to check R.layout.list_item (list_item.xml)

Comment: Its to simple and i gt confuse by getting code. So i got the point that i dont have to give background color to the row.xml file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom background for row layout - you have to make higlight animation by yourself. You can do this using selector layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_back"
        >

       </item>
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_back_tap"
        >          
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I know that Selector. But i want the default one. and i got it by rDroid's Answer.